# JS / JQuery execCommand problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, execcommand

I am having trouble (complete) with execCommand so you help much appreciated - I have no doubt I am barking up the wrong tree but ..... anyway

I have a div like this

```
<div class="editable" id="editor" contenteditable="true"> 
    <2>Some text in here</h2> blah blah blah ...
</div>
```

That is "editable" i.e. `document.designMode = 'on';` - it get's this "state" on focus. On blur it changes to `document.designMode = 'off';`

I have a "test button"

```
<input type="button" id="bold" value="Bold">
```

That when "clicked" makes the "highlighted text" bold - hence execCommand

So far I have something like this:

```
function getSelected() {
if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
else {
var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
return false;
}
return false;
}


$('#bold').click(function(){
var selection = getSelected();
alert(selection);
});
```

The alert (bold click) does give me the highlighted/selected text but I cannot work out how to "turn it" bold.  I guess I need to access the innerHTML or something?

Help much appreciated - thanks in advance. OH and I do not want to use either an i-frame or a textarea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly recommend using [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) for dealing with text selection.

> A cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library. It provides a simple standards-based API for performing common DOM Range and Selection tasks in all major browsers, abstracting away the wildly different implementations of this functionality between Internet Explorer and DOM-compliant browsers.

You can use the [CSS Class Applier Module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) to bold the text ([live demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html)).

Comment: Matt ummmmmm ... thanks VERY much for Rangy opens FAR more possibilities, not one I had come across.  It does not conflicy with UI Sortables so when I mean possibilities . as I said ... ummm.  Just need to fathom out a few things with it but it looks like one of those "invaluables".  Without going to far looks like I can really combine some aspects of HTML5 cross browser without conflicts.  Much appreciated hence 2 vote up and an answer

Comment: No problem. You're welcome. BTW, I'm pretty sure the maintainer is on SO. ***edit*** [found him](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down).